# how can I use special Font awesome character in Twig link()?

Tags: theming, 8

How can I use a special Font awesome character instead of the *text* parameter with `link($text, $url, $attributes)?

I tried the following code for the *Contact us* button, but it doesn't show the envelope symbol properly. Instead, it shows `#xf0e0;`.

```
{{ link('&#xf0e0;', 'base:contact', { 'class':['fa', 'fa-lg'] }) }}`
```

Is there any way to output that symbol without using the *fa-envelope* CSS class?

Comment: `but whatever i try i cant show "Envelope" character properly` what exactly is properly? Does the character not show up at all? or???

Comment: Yes, character not show up at all and instead of to showing the "Envelope" symbol is shown it's value " &#xf0e0;.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are really set on not using the class (and want to use the unicode char) just don't use `link()`, the $text parameter is escaped. Just build a link normally:

```
<a href="{{ path('contact.site_page') }}" class="contact-us-link"><i class="fa fa-lg">&#xf0e0;</i></a>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `fa` class sets FontAwesome for the element itself, only the `:before` pseudo-element.

Comment: `fa` applies to the element

Answer (score 3):

The point of the FontAwesome selectors is that you do not need to print out the Unicode equivalent for the character. FontAwesome usually works by adding a pseudo element before or after the HTML element using the class.

In this case, use the `fa fa-envelope` classes and optionally add in a class to hide the text with a text-indent or something.

```
{{ link('Contact Us', 'base:contact', { 'class':['fa', 'fa-envelope', 'fa-lg', 'contact-us-link'] }) }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your Consultation, But is there any method that i can achieve this purpose without using "fa-envelope" Class.

Comment: @MojtabaReyhani what happens if you remove `'fa-envelope',` in the above code? does it not work?

Comment: @Sssweat Thank you for your attention, yes, by remove the 'fa-envelope' class, in the above code, it does not work and doesn't show envelope symbol.

Comment: Why do you not want to add the `fa-envelope` class. That is exactly how you are supposed to use FontAwesome. If you want to do /not/ use that class, then you have to reconstruct the CSS that is already written for you. It is completely duplicate code to not use that class.